Why doesn't Comparer support 64-bit (long) delegate return type for lambda operations in C#?
I'm trying to create a priority queue in C# that consists of 64-bit (long) integers in DESCENDING order.  Unfortunately, it looks like .NET doesn't support this?
Here's the code that fails:
PriorityQueue<long, long> pq = new PriorityQueue<long, long>(Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => y - x));
And here are the errors it generates:

error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

It should be noted that everything works perfectly if I change all the "long" references to "int".
Is there a cast I can put somewhere to make this work or is this just a basic feature that C# doesn't support for whatever reason?

What does Compare need to return? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=net-6.0 Is that what you are doing? https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zg8CLw

Not sure what you were trying to do with y - x, that would give you incorrect results in some cases.
It was erroring because you were returning a long, and Compare expects an int which is:

0 for equal values
Positive where x > y
Negative where y > x

The simplest way to return the reverse comparison is to just flip the operands. Compare x against y rather than the other way round.
var comparer = Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
PriorityQueue<long, long> pq = new PriorityQueue<long, long>(comparer);


Yeah that was for a method that had very limited and predictable inputs so I was able to get away with that.  I do understand that Compare expects int instead of long; in fact, if you review the question title, what I wanted to know is if there's a way to pass long to Compare, as I don't know why it wouldn't support that.  That said, everything you covered is correct and your approach is better than what I was doing so I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.  Thanks!  Still wish I knew why it doesn't accept long, though...

@KrisCraig, it DOES accept long. There's no issue passing long values in. The problem is that the method MUST return an int and you were trying to return a long. The issue is the value you're trying to pass out, not the values you're trying to pass in.

if there's a way to pass long to Compare Did you check the link I provided as a comment to your question? It clearly shows how to do it.

@KrisCraig: Passing a long to Compare is fine, assuming it's a Comparer<long>. It's returning a long from Compare that's the problem. Claiming that Comparer<T> doesn't support long because you can't return a long from it is like saying that it doesn't support any type other than int. How do you expect a Comparer<String> to work?

Ok I just got the wording mixed up.  The return value is what I meant.

@KrisCraig: Why would that be particularly desirable? What benefit does it give over returning int given that you only need to return "negative, zero or positive"? Basically you can absolutely build a Comparer<long> which does whatever you need to, without returning a long. But no, there's no C# feature which lets you return a long from something (whether that's a delegate, method or property) that's declared to return int - and I'm personally glad of that. Fundamentally, you just need to look at the declaration of Comparer<T> - it returns int, not T.

It does support it.
You need to do this though:
IComparer<long> comparer = Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => y == x ? 0 : y > x ? 1 : -1)

Your (understandable) confusion stems from the parameter for Comparer<T>.Create being a dedicated "old-style" delegate that "hides" its signature a bit when you hover over the method that accepts it:
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y)

you are not seeing int anywhere just Comparison<long>, and assume that it's Func<T,T,T> whereas it actually is Func<T,T,int>.
Unfortunately it's late now to also add an overload for Comparer<T>.Create with a Func<T,T,int> parameter because it will create ambiguity for the compiler when you pass the lambda inline - the two delegates being functionally equivalent it won't be able to pick one method over the other.
The int return type is as others have commented for the actual contract of IComparer<T> - int CompareTo(T x, T y)
